# Discord.js Music Bot not working (Distube Framework)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, distube

I'm trying to create a Discord Music Bot with discord.js and the Distube Framework, the code is fine and I don't have any errors, but as soon as I try to play a music with my command ("/play song"), the bot joins the channel and sends the embed, but instantly state the music as finished and never plays it.

Here is my code:

`App.js`

```
const Distube = require("distube")
const { SoundCloudPlugin } = require("@distube/soundcloud")
const { SpotifyPlugin } = require("@distube/spotify")
/* eslint new-cap: ["error", { "properties": false }] */
client.distube = new Distube.default(client, {
    leaveOnEmpty: true,
    emptyCooldown: 30,
    leaveOnFinish: false,
    emitNewSongOnly: true,
    updateYouTubeDL: true,
    nsfw: true,
    youtubeCookie: process.env.ytcookie,
    plugins: [new SoundCloudPlugin(), new SpotifyPlugin()]
})
const status = (queue) => `Volume: \`${queue.volume}%\` | Loop: \`${queue.repeatMode ? queue.repeatMode === 2 ? "All Queue" : "This Song" : "Off"}\` | Autoplay: \`${queue.autoplay ? "On" : "Off"}\` | Filter: \`${queue.filters.join(", ") || "Off"}\``

client.distube
    .on("playSong", (queue, song) => {          //command to play a song
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setAuthor("Started Playing", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HELLSNAKES/Music-Slash-Bot/main/assets/music.gif")
            .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
            .setDescription(`[${song.name}](${song.url})`)
            .addField("**Views:**", song.views.toString(), true)
            .addField("**Like:**", song.likes.toString(), true)
            .addField("**Duration:**", song.formattedDuration.toString(), true)
            .addField("**Status**", status(queue).toString())
            .setFooter(`Requested by ${song.user.username}`, song.user.avatarURL())
            .setTimestamp()
        queue.textChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
    })
```

`play.js`

```
module.exports = {
    name: "play",
    description: "Playing music",
    options: [
        {
            name: "query",
            type: 3,
            description: "The song you want to play | Supported url: youtube,soundcloud,spotify",
            required: true
        }
    ],
    timeout: 5000,
    run: async (interaction, client) => {
        const voiceChannel = interaction.member.voice.channel
        const queue = await client.distube.getQueue(interaction)
        const query = interaction.options.get("query").value
        if (!voiceChannel) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: "Please join a voice channel!", ephemeral: true })
        }
        if (queue) {
            if (interaction.member.guild.me.voice.channelId !== interaction.member.voice.channelId) {
                return interaction.reply({ content: "You are not on the same voice channel as me!", ephemeral: true })
            }
        }
        await interaction.reply("**Searching and attempting...**")
        await interaction.editReply("Searching done :ok_hand: ")
        client.distube.play(voiceChannel, query, { //Should play the song
            textChannel: interaction.channel,
            member: interaction.member
        })
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm also having this issues, did you ever get a solution, the 'solution' below did not work for me. The documentation isnt the best.

I only get this issue when I dpeloy to heroku, running on my local machine it works fine.

Comment: Update: It was the Heroku stack 22 I was hosting my bot on causing my issue, downgrading to stack 20 fixed it for me, if you are running locally and having the issue check this: https://github.com/skick1234/DisTube/issues/220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue caused by the delay between calling a song and actually starting to play it if `leaveOnFinish` is toggled on. It can be fixed by setting `leaveOnFinish` to false and then waiting a bit after the queue has ended to disconnect the bot. Here's how I have setup my bot to leave 2 minutes after the final song is played.

```js
      setTimeout(async () => {
        if (!queue.textChannel.guild.me.voice.channelId) {
          return clearTimeout();
        }
        let queue_music = await client.distube.getQueue(queue.voiceChannel);

        if (queue_music !== undefined && queue_music.playing) {
          clearTimeout();
        } else if (queue_music == undefined || queue_music.songs.length === 0) {
          queue.textChannel
            .send({
              embeds: [
                new MessageEmbed()
                  .setDescription("Finished!")
              ],
            })
            .catch(() => { })
          queue.stop(client.voice.channel)
        }
      }, 120000)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered this problem myself but I can't solve it, some youtube links store the wrong data and distube can't handle it. Try playing other videos to see if they have this problem.
Also try provide ytcookie in distube